# How to scrape with rvest?

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I need to get three different numbers (in yellow, see picture) from this page:

https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?authorId=7006040753

[image]

I used this code using `rvest` and `inspectorgadget`:

```
site=read_html("https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?authorId=7006040753") 
hindex=site %>% html_node(".row3 .valueColumn span")%>% html_text()
documents=site %>% html_node("#docCntLnk")%>% html_text()
citations=site %>% html_node("#totalCiteCount")%>% html_text()
print(citations)
```

I can get the `h-index` and `documents` but the citations do not work

Can you help me?

Comment: Looked like a quick fix at first glance, but this value seems to be loaded dynamically (if you look at the source code, you'll notice the number doesn't appear anywhere) meaning you'll first have to render the website using e.g. PhantomJS or RSelenium and download/process the website afterwards with rvest

Comment: I just tried PhantomJS and also get issues here as the page processing seems to be blocked. So rather use RSelenium (unfortunately I have no knowledge about this) or maybe work with the number of documents instead of the total citations which can be scraped easier (and makes more sense imho as it is more important in how many documents sth is cited and not how often per document)

Comment: Hello TomS, thank you for the comment...what do you mean with "if you look at the source code, you'll notice the number doesn't appear anywhere". Actually in the html source code I found `<input type="hidden" name="ctoCount" value="51971">` and also `<span id="totalCiteCount">51971</span>`.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unprecise. If you use right click -> show page source (instead of e.g. the browser "Inspect element" function) it looks like this: `<span id="totalCiteCount"></span>` This is also what you get when opening and downloading the page with PhantomJS due to some errors => page is not rendered. Also if you scrape the parent node `div class="valueColumn" data-citedbythreshold="false">` you get the whole row except the desired value

Comment: Hi Guglielmo, related question: Have you by any chance found a way to get a list of all existing Scopus author ids? I noticed they are using up to 11 seemingly random digits so just scraping all of them (99 billion pages) seems very inefficient/impossible but I can't find a complete list anywhere..Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I've found a solution - I noticed the value took some time to load so I included a little timeout in the PhnatomJS script. Now it works on my machine with the following R code:

```
setwd("path/to/phantomjs/bin")
system('phantomjs readexample.js') # call PhantomJS script (stored in phantomjs/bin)

totalCiteCount <- "rendered_page.html" %>% # "rendered_page.html" is created by PhantomJS
   read_html() %>%
   html_nodes("#totalCiteCount") %>%
   html_text()

## totalCiteCount
## [1] "52018"
```

The corresponding PhantomJS script file "readexample.js" looks like the following (kudos to https://www.r-bloggers.com/web-scraping-javascript-rendered-sites/):

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var url ='https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?authorId=7006040753';
var fs = require('fs'); 
var page = webPage.create();
var system = require('system');

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)';

page.open(url, function (status) {
        setTimeout(function() {
               fs.write('rendered_page.html', page.content, 'w');
            phantom.exit();
    }, 2500);
});
```

The code throws the following errors in R, but at least the value is scraped correctly.

```
> system('phantomjs readexample.js') TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'mutation.addedNodes.forEach')

  https://www.scopus.com/gzip_N1846232499/bundles/SiteCatalystTop.js:73  :0 in forEach   https://www.scopus.com/gzip_N1846232499/bundles/SiteCatalystTop.js:73 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SDM

  https://www.scopus.com/gzip_N1729184664/bundles/AuthorProfileTop.js:73 in sendIndex   https://www.scopus.com/gzip_N1729184664/bundles/AuthorProfileTop.js:67 in loadEvents
```

Using PhantomJS is quite convenient as you don't have to install anything (so also works if you don't have admin rights on your machine). Simply [download](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) the .zip file and unpack it to any folder. Afterwards set the working directory in R (`setwd()`) to the "phantomjs/bin" folder and it works.

You can also change the PhantomJS scripte (iteratively if desired) in R e.g. to pass different URLs to the script in a loop. Example:

```
for (i in 1:n_urls) {

   url_var <- urls[i] # assuming you have created a var "urls" with multiple URLs before
   lines <- readLines("readexample.js")
   lines[2] <- paste0("var url ='", url_var ,"';") # exchange code line with new URL
   writeLines(lines, "readexample.js") # new url is stored in the PhantomJS script

   system('phantomjs readexample.js')

   # <any code> #

}
```

Hope this brings you one step further?

Comment: Great TomS! I will try your solution...
Thank you.

Comment: Super!!!!Tried with iterations...it works perfectly! Thank you a lot Tom!!